# Moving Xcode certificate to new system for iPhone Dev

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate

In Apple's Provisioning Portal "How To" under Certificates, there is a section called "Saving your Private Key and Transferring to other Systems". Now this is what I'm doing (I have rebuilt my machine with a new HDD and therefore have access to my previous OS build) and I'm looking to backup my private key so I can install it on my new OS build and start codesigning iPhone Applications again.

The problem is, in the [how to](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action), it says to backup the "<First Name> <Last Name> public certificate that is paired with it." (although the image is a private key):
[image]

And so when I checked my KeyChain, I've found 9 Private keys and 9 Public keys with my name on, so how do I know what I'm looking for?

I found in the first private key, it has this access control:
[image]

But when importing this I get a message saying it cannot import :(

So really, I just want to know which one I need to import - I guess I can try trial and error with them but would like to know either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You click on the small triangle at the left of the key and the one that has "iPhone Developer:"First Name" "Last Name" as a child is the one you want.

BTW, it's Xcode, not xCode :-).

Comment: How do you get the triangle to appear? On my new build it's not there in keychain (although I remember doing this before). I'll boot up my old build and see if I can get it. Ps. Xcode, xCode, Tomato, Tomato XD

Comment: Well the triangle is in the keychain app on the system where you already have the keys installed.

Comment: Yea thanks, just sorted it! Xcode lets me test on device again. Thanks